# почему в MASM32 Library Reference нету всех макросов и подпрограмм?

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Я скачал masm32 с офф. сайта и установил его. В итоге я получил папку `masm32` с разными файлами. В этой папке есть программа под названием `qeditor.exe`, и в этой программе я захожу в Menu Help -> MASM32 Library Reference. Дальше в окне `MASM32 Library Reference` у меня собственно и есть список разных макросов и подпрограмм.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь допустим у меня есть след код:

```
_DATA SEGMENT

    folderName BYTE "/NewFolder", 0
    fullFolderName BYTE "C:/PN/Grupa03/"
    buffor BYTE 250 dup(0)

_DATA ENDS
;------------
_TEXT SEGMENT
main proc

    push 0
    push OFFSET fullFolderName
    call CreateDirectoryA

    push OFFSET buffor
    push 255
    call GetCurrentDirectoryA

    push OFFSET folderName
    push OFFSEt buffor
    call lstrcatA

    push 0
    push OFFSET buffor
    call CreateDirectoryA

    push 0
    call ExitProcess
main endp
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

В коде я использую `CreateDirectoryA` и `GetCurrentDirectoryA`, но я не могу найти их в `MASM32 Library Reference`, или может я не там ищу? Где мне найти примеры работ этих макросов?

Comment: Видимо потому что CreateDirectoryA и GetCurrentDirectoryA относятся не к библиотеке MASM32, а к Win API, нужно искать соответствующий справочник.

Answer (score 0):

Читай первоисточники, к примеру [Создание директории](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya?source=docs), он описан на С++, но сути дела это не меняет, подготавливай параметры так как там описано и получай результат как положено.